# Grab chars verbatim from string

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, list, char

I have a sting that I want to grab each char from. However, when this string contains a backslash it seems to grab a hexadecimal or something. I'm using **python3**.

```
def parse(content):
    tmp = []
    for c in content:
        tmp.append(row[c])
    return tmp
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
>>> parse("abc\x7fa")
['a', 'b', 'c', '\x7f', 'a']
```

Obviously, this is not what I want. I want the following output:

```
>>> parse("abc\x7fa")
['a', 'b', 'c', '\', 'x', '7', 'f', 'a']
```

I have also tried other alternatives, such as using

```
for c in row:
```

and:

```
return [c for c in content]
```

But all of them insist on keeping `'\x7f'` in the output.

Answer (score 2):

`\x7f` represents one character in python.
in python, `"\"` is used for special characters, etc., and `\x7f` is the delete character (byte 27)
the python representation of `"abc\x7fa"` is `"abc\\x7fa"`.

Comment: Indeed! Also one could consider a raw string literal, `r"abc\x7fa"`, where backslash is not interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `parse` function can be replaced by a call to `list`. The issue is that the backslash is not escaped, so the backslash and following chars are interpreted as one character. Try `list(r"abc\x7fa")` and have a look at [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).